# Regular Languages and Concatenation

Tags: concatenation, regular-language, finite-automata, fsm

Regular languages are closed under concatenation - this is demonstrable by having the accepting state(s) of one language with an epsilon transition to the start state of the next language.

If we consider the language L = {a^n | n >=0}, this language is regular (it is simply a*). If we concatenate it with another language L = {b^n | n >=0}, which is also regular, we end up with a^nb^n, but we obviously know this isn't regular.

Where am I going wrong with my logic here?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be more appropriate for cs.stackexchange.com. It's more pedagogical than practical.

Comment: The concatenation is `a*b*`, surely?

Comment: consider a string in L1 'aaa' and in L2 'b' according to your example. now after concatenation 'aaab' will come which is not in a^nb^n

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The definition of the concatenation of two languages L<sub>1</sub> and L<sub>2</sub> is the set of all strings wx where w ∈ L<sub>1</sub> and x ∈ L<sub>2</sub>. This means that L<sub>1</sub>L<sub>2</sub> consists of all possible strings formed by pairing one string from L<sub>1</sub> and one string from L<sub>2</sub>, which isn't necessarily the same as pairing up matching strings from each language.

As a result, as @Oli Charlesworth pointed out, the language you get back here isn't actually { a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> | n in N }. Instead, it's the language { a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>m</sup> | n in N and m in N }, which is the language a*b*. This language is regular, since it's given by the regular languages.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That sounds like cross product. Is concatenation same as cross / cartesian product?

Comment: @anir Good question! Language concatenation is similar to but not the same as the Cartesian product. For one, the types involved are different: Cartesian products are defined for arbitrary sets while language concatenation only works on sets of strings, and the Cartesian product of two sets forms a set of pairs while language concatenation produces a set of strings. Also, the cardinalities of the sets may be different; {a, aa} $times; {a, aa} = {(aa, a), (aa, aa), (a, a), (a, aa) } while {a, aa}{a, aa} = {aa, aaa, aaaa}.